# Sending and receiving emails for exchange account using Oauth 2 in php

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, outlook, phpmailer, exchange-server

I want to send receive from exchange account using OAuth in PHP. Currently I'm using Phpmailer library but it requires password for it, How to implement it without password? After using gmail_xoauth.php library from phpmailer i am getting following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException: invalid_grant in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\GoogleOauthLogin\PHPMailer5\vendor\league\oauth2-google\src\Provider\Google.php:120
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\GoogleOauthLogin\PHPMailer5\vendor\league\oauth2-client\src\Provider\AbstractProvider.php(613): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google->checkResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\GoogleOauthLogin\PHPMailer5\vendor\league\oauth2-client\src\Provider\AbstractProvider.php(528): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getParsedResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\GoogleOauthLogin\PHPMailer5\class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php(69): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getAccessToken(Object(League\OAuth2\Client\Grant\RefreshToken), Array)
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\GoogleOauthLogin\PHPMailer5\class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php(74): PHPMailerOAuthGoogle->getT in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\GoogleOauthLogin\PHPMailer5\vendor\league\oauth2-google\src\Provider\Google.php on line 120
```

Comment: Please include the code of what you have done, with proper errors and i/o.

Comment: You could try [reading the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2) on this exact subject (the docs need updating), and the [gmail oauth example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps) provided with PHPMailer. Oauth is horrible to work with for email, but it does work.

Comment: @Synchro thanks for help, i am using that example but getting error as mentioned above, how can it removed?

Comment: Sounds like whatever grant your requesting is invalid? You'll need to check gmail's oauth docs on that - this is the kind of thing I meant when I said "Oauth is horrible to work with".

Comment: @Syncro Thanks.. issue is now resolved